# Creating an interactive graph but cannot find defined widget referenced

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm trying to create an interactive graph which uses a dataframe (defined using a second function) which should then be updated with the defined widgets. The code runs fine if I don't make the plot interactive (i.e. I just run my plot function with static values). I've tried combing through some other questions but can't seem to find what I'm looking for (maybe I'm not asking the right qestions).

My original code:

```
%matplotlib inline
style = {'description_width':'initial'}

TR = widgets.BoundedFloatText(value=1734,min=0,max=10000,step=10,description='Top Reservoir (TVDMSL):',style=style,disabled=False)
BR = widgets.BoundedFloatText(value=1771,min=0,max=10000,step=10,description='Base Reservoir (TVDMSL):',style=style,disabled=False)
NGw = widgets.BoundedFloatText(value=0.88,min=0,max=1,step=0.1,description='NTG (fraction):',style=style,disabled=False)
WD = widgets.BoundedFloatText(value=127,min=0,max=10000,step=10,description='Water depth (m):',style=style,disabled=False)
RR = widgets.BoundedFloatText(value=3500,min=0,max=10000,step=100,description='Reservoir radius (m):',style=style,disabled=False)
D = widgets.BoundedFloatText(value=13.2,min=0,max=10000,step=10,description='Depletion (MPa):',style=style,disabled=False)
nuw = widgets.BoundedFloatText(value=0.29,min=0,max=1,step=0.01,description='Poissons Ratio (bar):',style=style,disabled=False)
Ew = widgets.BoundedFloatText(value=7.9,min=0,max=10000,step=1,description='Youngs Modulus (GPa):',style=style,disabled=False)

def plot(BR,TR,NGw,WD,Ew,nuw,RR,e,intv,D):
    
    # run function without print to get the results dataframe
    with HiddenPrints():
        df_results = geertsma(BR,TR,NGw,WD,Ew,nuw,RR,e,intv,D)
    
    # defining x-y data for sea bed and reservoir depth
    Vd_OB = df_results['Vertical displacement (cm)'].iloc[0]
    Vd_UB = df_results['Vertical displacement (cm)'].iloc[-1]
    x = [(Vd_UB-1),(Vd_OB+5)]
    Seabed_y = (WD,WD)
    Res_top_y = (TR,TR)
    Res_base_y = (BR, BR)
    
    # formatting plot
    
    f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,10))
    ax.set_ylim([0,e])   # setting y plot limit between 0 and depth of interest
    ax.set_xlim(x)   # setting x plot limit
    ax.axhline(y=0, color='darkgrey')    # Adding axis through origin
    ax.axvline(x=0, color='darkgrey')    # Adding axis through origin
    
    # plotting data
    ax.plot(x,Seabed_y,color='steelblue', label='Seabed')    # Plotting seabed level
    ax.plot(x,Res_top_y,color='darkorange', label='Top reservoir')    # plotting top res
    ax.plot(x,Res_base_y,color='gold', label='Base reservoir')      # plotting base res
    ax.plot(df_results['Vertical displacement (cm)'], df_results['Depth'], color='k', label='displacement profile')   # plotting displacement profile
    
    # formatting plot/data
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    ax.tick_params(top=True, labeltop=True, bottom=False, labelbottom=False)
    ax.set_title('Vertical Displacement Profile')
    ax.set_xlabel('Vertical displacement (cm)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Depth (TVDm)')
    ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
    ax.legend()

interactive_plot = interactive(plot,{'BR':BR,'TR':TR,'NGw':NGw,'WD':WD,'Ew':Ew,'nuw':nuw,'RR':RR,'e':e,'intv':int,'D':D })
```

I get the following error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[51], line 58
     55 nuw = widgets.BoundedFloatText(value=0.29,min=0,max=1,step=0.01,description='Poissons Ratio (bar):',style=style,disabled=False)
     56 Ew = widgets.BoundedFloatText(value=7.9,min=0,max=10000,step=1,description='Youngs Modulus (GPa):',style=style,disabled=False)
---> 58 interactive_plot = interactive(plot,{'BR':BR,'TR':TR,'NGw':NGw,'WD':WD,'Ew':Ew,'nuw':nuw,'RR':RR,'e':e,'intv':int,'D':D })
     60 #plot(BR.value,TR.value,NGw.value,WD.value,Ew.value,nuw.value,RR.value,e.value,intv.value,D.value)
     61 
     62 #out = widgets.interactive_output(plot, {'BR':BR,'TR':TR,'NGw':NGw,'WD':WD,'Ew':Ew,'nuw':nuw,'RR':RR,'e':e,'intv':int,'D':D})

File C:\Appl\my_env\Lib\site-packages\ipywidgets\widgets\interaction.py:172, in interactive.__init__(self, _interactive__interact_f, _interactive__options, **kwargs)
    169 self.manual_name = __options.get("manual_name", "Run Interact")
    170 self.auto_display = __options.get("auto_display", False)
--> 172 new_kwargs = self.find_abbreviations(kwargs)
    173 # Before we proceed, let's make sure that the user has passed a set of args+kwargs
    174 # that will lead to a valid call of the function. This protects against unspecified
    175 # and doubly-specified arguments.
    176 try:

File C:\Appl\my_env\Lib\site-packages\ipywidgets\widgets\interaction.py:272, in interactive.find_abbreviations(self, kwargs)
    270     for name, value, default in _yield_abbreviations_for_parameter(param, kwargs):
    271         if value is empty:
--> 272             raise ValueError('cannot find widget or abbreviation for argument: {!r}'.format(name))
    273         new_kwargs.append((name, value, default))
    274 return new_kwargs

ValueError: cannot find widget or abbreviation for argument: 'BR'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved this. I was calling interactive plot incorrectly so function was the same but instead of:

```
interactive_plot = interactive(plot,{'BR':BR,'TR':TR,'NGw':NGw,'WD':WD,'Ew':Ew,'nuw':nuw,'RR':RR,'e':e,'intv':int,'D':D })
```

I used:

```
out3 = widgets.interactive_output(plot,{'BR':BR,'TR':TR,'NGw':NGw,'WD':WD,'Ew':Ew,'nuw':nuw,'RR':RR,'e':e,'intv':intv,'D':D })
widgets.VBox([out3])
```

which worked as I wanted :)